# 2 way repeated ANOVA did not show sphericity test

Tags: r, statistics, anova

There were 4 levels of treatment over 11 sampling time points. Each treatment had 3 identical systems. And samples were analyzed for different parameters. So I used 2 way repeated measures anova, for example:

```
ezANOVA(data = WP4, dv = parameter1, wid = System, within = Time, between = Treatment, type=3)
```

However, it produced anova table without sphericity test on some parameters, like below:

```
Warning: NaNs producedWarning: NaNs produced$ANOVA
          Effect DFn DFd         F            p p<.05       ges
2      Treatment   3   8  2.255871 1.590810e-01       0.2934692
3           Time  10  80 35.989273 1.524902e-25     * 0.6960297
4 Treatment:Time  30  80  7.574502 2.275032e-13     * 0.5911306
```

Please let me know if you need more information to crack my problem. Thanks.

I would like to have the complete anova table with $`Mauchly's Test for Sphericity` and $`Sphericity Corrections`.

Comment: Hi Huang, could you please post your data? I'll post some instructions on how to do that.

Comment: It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.